# How to set different icon in ALT+TAB view and taskbar

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, icons, taskbar

I have a Winform application and I would set two different icons, one for the application shown in the taskbar and the left-upper corner of the window and a different one for the ALT+TAB switch. 
The properties Icon of the Form sets only the small one but seems that it is used also for the ALT+TAB view.
In Visual Studio 2012 I've already tried to select a diffenrent icon under Project Properties > Application > Resources > Icon and Manifest.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution which is quite simple. Basically I created a multi-size icon with the same image (64x64, 32x32...) and I changed the 16x16 size with another icon. In this way you can have different type of icon inside one.